# How to solve new project colours.xml error?

Tags: android, android-studio

Once I create a new project I get an error

> C:\Users\User\Desktop\4Find\app\src\main\res\values\colors.xml:9:18: Error: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.

My colours.xml file at default looks as below;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
    <component name="AndroidLayouts">
        <shared>
            <config />
        </shared>
    </component>
    <component name="AndroidLogFilters">
        <option n
```

Comment: post full xml. this is not how colors.xml should look like

Comment: Not a valid xml file.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 It is exactly as it looks defaultly when I create a project

Comment: your xml is obviously invalid. If you say that it is this like from the start, then you probably have problems with Android Studio installation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced this problem before. Instead of reinstall it, what i did was delete AndroidStudio file which located at C:\Users\YourUserName\.AndroidStudio3.2 (.AndroidStudio file name should depends on your android studio version). This will reset android studio to default setting.

Hope this could help you.

Comment: Yes. It did help. Thank you!

Comment: I did the same but the problem persists. I tried resinstalling as well

Answer (score 0):

**colors.xml** should be look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#17AC82</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#17AC82</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#17AC82</color>
     ...........
</resources>
```

Comment: Correct but Still gives an error                                                                                           
Android resource compilation failed
Output:  C:\Users\User\Desktop\4Find\app\src\main\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher.xml:16: error: unclosed token.

Comment: The color related issue is fixed. Please check the `ic_launcher.xml` in **mipmap-anydpi-v26** token unclosed.  Would you please share this `ic_launcher.xml` from **mipmap-anydpi-v26** directory?

Comment: @ErickIvuto is your problem solved ?

Comment: The solution was resetting android studio but your solution also worked. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something went wrong. It's not how colors.xml should look like, it's even not valid XML.

You can edit colors.xml but in my experience project will have other issues in its resources.
Try to create new project one more time.

Comment: Thank you I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

Delete Android Studio file which located at

```
C:\Users\YourUserName\.AndroidStudio(version)
```